# Pattern Locking in android

Tags: android

i want to implement pattern locking in my app, so that user has to draw a pattern before using the application.

Can anyone suggest me how to do that?

Comment: At last How you done it.....? Can you make me help to implementing it....

Comment: You could have a look on Android source  :-) Or [touch here](https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/).

Comment: [check this library](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/android-lock-pattern/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [this link](http://haibison.github.io/android-lockpattern/). I tested it and it is a very good example.

Comment: it has been removed now .. any other link ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking of building this myself and i have some idea's.
One thing you could do is just extend the `View` class and draw the everything in the `onDraw()` method and handle input in the `onTouchEvent()` method.