# Use Android Pattern Lock

Tags: android, locking, design-patterns

Is there any way of using the excisting pattern lock or password from the android security, and "modify" so each time the pattern/password have been drawned wrong the 5. time it will show a toast on the screen ? Or do i have to create my own pattern/password application ?

Comment: You would have to find the source code and modify it, or start with your own copy from scratch.

Comment: Follow [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10476845/779408). It is a very good example.

Answer (score 0):

You *might* be able to implement a [DeviceAdminReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html#onPasswordFailed%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29)

From it's description it should be notified of failed password attempts but it's not really clear from the description if that includes lock screen attempts.

If that did work from a service or something you might be able to launch a toast though.

---

[Edit] Found a better [resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)